# CouchDB - Figuring out database security

Tags: security, nosql, couchdb, validation

CouchDB offers validation prior to allowing an object/row to be inserted into the database. This make sure that if you have a public facing couch application, you're database won't be filled with junk by just anyone.

```
User <-> CouchDB
```

However, I'm tring to figure out what that looks like comming from the standard application design process where you have a [trusted middle layer that does much of the auth work](http://blog.couchbase.com/whats-new-in-couchdb-1-0-part-4-securityn-stuff). For example, most apps place Ruby or PHP between the database and user agent which allows the application to figure out information about the user agent before allowing something like a post to be saved to the database.

```
User -> Ruby -> MySQL
User <- Ruby <- MySQL
```

**How do you trust the user to do administrative tasks when the user can't be trusted?**

For example, how would you do something like "email verification" prior to inserting a user row using just couchDB? You can't let the *user agent insert the row* - because they would fill the system with spam accounts. On the other hand, there is no middle layer either that can insert the row after they click the link in the email.

How about this, I would assume that you would allow anyone to enter their email by creating a new record in a public table like `email_verify`. This is something that a public user agent could do as the table would not do anything in the application - it would just be a holding tank.

Then node.js could track the _changes feed and send an activation email while creating a new entry in a private table (like `email_confirm`) (node.js would serve as a trusted middle layer). If the user clicks that link and comes back then... [unknown] ... and node.js could finally create a record in the private user table (`user`).

At this point we could then rely on couchdb validation for the rest of the application since we got a confirmed user account created.

*As more background* lets imagine a discussion built on couchdb that anyone can register for. We don't want to allow just anyone to directly submit content without some kind of verification - yet the user agents all *directly run the system*. (Tables would be `Thread`, `Comment`, & `User`). How would this work?

Comment: I don't get what it is about "tables"? Are you talking of databases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think about adding roles to existing users in this issue.

Using couchdb's validation and changing `_design/_auth` can be a good idea to add `email`, `email_verified` and randomly generated `email_verification_code` in `_users` database when the user firsts registers.

To send mail, get confirmation, resend confirmation you can use external processes. (for an example usage of external process you can check couchdb-lucene).

And at last you can again do a quick check in _design/_auth in user update process if verification code matches and add `verified_user` role for that user.

This way all your requests would pass over couchdb, you would use external process only when you need to send mail and get confirmation.

Edit : Forgot to add (since it was pretty obvious), I would add verified_user role to database readers.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just make use of [CouchDb's Validation](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/validation.html) ?

Users could be flagged. Upon registration, a User is added to the Users database. He gets his mail and then is flagged "valid:true" or something like this upon answering to that mail or clicking a link.

With validation users could not only be "logged in/out" but also access authorization can be implemented with more granular access rights. E.g.: Only mark threads solved if one is the author, admin, whatever...

Or does this seem impracticable?

Comment: What would this look like in an actual working program though? Who flags the user as "valid:true"? The goal is that the users run the database - but the users can't be trusted with stuff like this so that means a "middle-ware" solution (like Node.js or PHP) would have to come in right? Or is it possible to use 100% pure couchDB to solve stuff like this?

Comment: Good question. Is the database distributed to the users via replication(a couchapp?) or what is meant with "the users run the database"? 

If you are talking of replicating the db to users' local couchdb instances, then you could handle this in a "master" application where users must also configure replication towards their couchdb.

On the other hand this also gives me headaches: How can you prohibit users to replicate "your" application database to someplace else... 

I must say, that I am not a well trained CouchDB developer, so second opinions would really matter here.

Comment: Well, the goal I have for running a couchdb application is that it is self-sufficient (doesn't rely on Apache or Ruby/Python/PHP to run). Since couchdb can handle 1,000's of concurrent users (giving them the _design/_view/_attachment docs) I can "offload" a lot of the logic into JavaScript and get their machines to process everything instead of running PHP or Ruby on the server. So, in essence I can build the application out of pure HTML and JavaScript and run it in the users browsers to use the full power of CouchDB. In other words, I'd like CouchDB to be the only thing I need to run my site.

Comment: Oh, and for the time being I don't really care about replication to the users machines. Though that is a neat feature I need to figure out how to use. ;)

Comment: Did you have a look at the "_users" database? I think one option would be to put users into different groups with different read/write access  to your databases?

Comment: I think you're thinking about this too simplistically. I could manually *approve every user*. However, that is a big waste of energy and I would rather juat have them verify there email and answer a recaptcha. However, if the application is pure HTML/JS couchapp - then there is no "trusted" party that can insert a row into the user table. This isn't a problem with a middle-ware solution like Ruby (which I can trust because it runs on my server) to insert rows into the database. However, since couchdb advertises that you can run a whole application off HTML/JS - then there must be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

After talking with some people on #couchdb IRC, it seems that they can't figure out out a way to do something administrative (like activation users that click on a email link) with out using a "backend" process like a node.js server which keeps track of the _changes feed.

I was hoping for a pure couchdb app - but it seems like couchdb still has a little ways to go.

Still, the good news is that you can hand off 80% of your applications logic/processing to your users. The other 20% will be 1) a node.js instance for things like sending emails or checking recaptcha and 2) record validation functions running in your couchdb, and 3) map/reduce (query) functions. These three things cannot be offloaded to something "untrusted" like a user-agent.